# merge two queries with different where into 1

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure as follows.

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(...)

INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT  MeasureDate, col1, col2
FROM Table1
WHERE Col3 = 1

INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT  MeasureDate, col1, col2
FROM Table1
WHERE Col3 = 1
AND Col4 = 7000

SELECT SUM(col1) / SUM(col2) AS Percentage, MAX(), MeasureDate
FROM @Temp
GROUP BY MeasureDate
```

I do two inserts into the temp table, 2nd insert with an extra WHERE but same columns same table, then I do SUM(col1) / SUM(col2) on the temp table to return the result I need. Is there a way to merge all these inserts and selects into one statement so I don't use a temp table and do a single select from Table1? Or even if I still need the temp table, merge the selects into one select instead of two separate selects? Stored procedure works fine as it is, just looking for a way to shorten it.

Thanks.

Comment: it is possible to do that but you better give some more detail. is not clear why you are putting duplicate data into the temp table, if this is a requirement or a mistake and that makes a huge difference when building a query.

Comment: You're right, I corrected the query, two queries are different, one is where col3=2 and the other is where col3=1 and col4=7000. It's not duplicate data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  MeasureDate, col1, col2
FROM Table1
WHERE Col3 = 2
  or (Col3 = 1 AND Col4 = 7000);


SELECT  sum(col1) / sum(col2) AS Percentage , GROUP BY MeasureDate
FROM Table1
WHERE Col3 = 2
  or (Col3 = 1 AND Col4 = 7000)
GROUP BY MeasureDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just combine the conditions in the first two queries with an `or` operator:

```
SELECT   SUM(col1) / SUM(col2) AS Percentage, MeasureDate
FROM     Table1
WHERE    (Col3 = 2) OR (Col3 = 1 AND Col4 = 7000)
GROUP BY MeasureDate
```